# Mavericks Open Directory Setup

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app

I am trying to setup the Open Directory server and it keeps failing stating that

```
/etc/openldap/slapd_macosxserver.conf: line 229: invalid path: No such file or directory
```

This is on a newly installed server. Was there something else besides running through the wizard that I was supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing folder that the error is referring to is `/var/db/openldap/openldap-data`. This database directory must exist prior to running slapd. Try creating the folder if it doesn't exist and make sure that the folder is read/write by the system.